# Plotting functions on IPE

Tags: installing, plot, ipe

IPE Drawing Tool is a free open source software for graphing. It follows friendly with TeX programming and writing, and that's when my question comes along.

I've been trying, for a few days now, to plot function (mostly trigonometric, polynomial and exponential simple functions) on IPE by trying to install *ipelets*, but I was completely unsuccessful. I found some of them, but couldn't install them. When I tried to copy the `.lua` addons to the *ipelets* folder, I couldn't open the software anymore. Specifically I got interested by [IpePlot](https://github.com/lahvak/ipeplots/blob/master/manual.pdf), but I really couldn't install it.

So, how could I plot professional looking function graphics, since I can't do it with IPE drawing tool? Am I doing something wrong?

---

Here are a few more details on how I've installed IPE and IPEPlots ipelet. I'm on Windows 7 Professional right now.

I've download IPE software from [here](https://ipe.otfried.org/). Then I extracted its contents on a folder directly o C: main directory. Here are its contents:

[image]

After that, I've download the ipelet from this [link](https://github.com/lahvak/ipeplots). I've put the `plots.lua` inside the already existing folder, like this:

[image]

And then, when I go to `bin` folder and try to open the software, it doesn't work. That's the full problem.

Comment: Examples include pgfplots, asymptote, tikz and pstricks. The ordering is intentional but only my personal opinion.

Comment: Yeah, tikz will be my next approach. But I'd really prefer not to touch on that until I really have to :)

Comment: Just as suggestion: Try `pgfplots` first instead of the manual TikZ approach. It makes plotting much easier.

Comment: How did you try to install `ipeplots`? I created an `ipelets` directory within my `.ipe` directory, and created `plots.lua` within that and it worked just fine.

Comment: @AntoineEgo I have updated the question so you can see what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I tried the previous suggestion on getting IPEPortable, but it got to the same problem. It'd help me so much if I could install that ipelet. Any suggestion on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check the main Ipelets directory from  Help Show Configuration this is where the lua file must go.

[image]

Download the Plots Manual from https://github.com/lahvak/ipeplots/raw/master/manual.pdf

Download the Plots Lua file from https://github.com/lahvak/ipeplots/raw/master/plots.lua
**Make sure you download this master copy** (in many browsers hover and use right click save link as)

Place the Lua file in the directory from the configuration Ipelets folder
Ideally in your system environment there should be set IPELETPATH=drive:folder/as/above

Restart IPE and check plots is showing

[image]

Comment: Oh man, that's awesome. Just one question: The IPELETPATH, do I put it inside the `ipe.conf` file?

Comment: Sorry your win 7 so go to Control Panel System > advanced system settings "environment Variables" and add new if its not already there. Variable name is IPELETPATH value is the path c:\....but I don't use it so don't know if its really needed